# append a constant and all lower natural numbers to the numbers to a list

Tags: r, list, append

Is there an easy way to add all the numbers (1:constant) to a list, as in the example below, without typing them out by hand (or using a for loop)?

```
> list <- c(1:10)
> constant <- 3
> unique(c(list,list+1,list+2,list+3))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

I'd like to be able to assign a constant, and append the constant and all lower natural numbers to the numbers in my list.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's what I'm trying to do, except without a for loop:

```
> list <- c(1:10)
> list2 <- c(1:10)
> constant <- 3
> for(i in 1:constant){
+ list2<-unique(c(list2,list+i))
+ }
> list2
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not perfectly efficient, but it's better than a for loop:

```
v <- 1:10  ## better not to call this "list"
constant <- 3
unique(c(outer(0:constant,v,"+")))
```